# POST/REDIRECT/GET what's wrong?

Tags: php

I have a website where any visitor can subscribe to receive the newsletter.I encountered the problem of having my resubmitted when everytime when i refreshed the page.I solved it by applying the PRG concept. Now a user never submits the same form twice, i have just one problem  : i have designed the form in such a way that when the is  succesfully/or fails  a message is display under the input fields. Unfortunatly now that i have the PRG concept applied i never get any message displayed . What to do ?

index.php - where i have the divs containing the submit form and the message display

```
        <div id="newsletter" >
            <form id="abonat" name="abonat" action="formular.php" method="post" onsubmit="return golire()" autocomplete="on"  > 
            <span>Subscribe</span>
            <input type="text" id="nume" name="nume"  placeholder="Name" required />
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off"  required/> 
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="button" style="width:26%;float:left;" /> 

            </form>
    </div>  

    <div id="mesaj_newsletter">
        <span><?php if (isset($mesaj)) echo $mesaj; ?> </span>
    </div>
```

formular.php - where the validation takes place,and the message is decided

```
include('conect.php');    
function validEmail($email){
    //code that verifies if it is a valid email adress
}

if( (isset($_POST['email']))&&(isset($_POST['nume'])) ){
    $nume=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nume']);
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $z=1;
    if(validEmail($email)==TRUE){
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM abonat");
        while($data=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                if(($data[1]==$email)||($data[2]==$nume))
                    $z=0;
        }

        if($z==1){
           mysql_query("INSERT INTO abonat(email,nume) VALUES ('$email','$nume')");
           $mesaj="Your email has been registered";
        }
        else $mesaj="You are already registered";   
    }
    else $mesaj="You have not entered a valid email adress";
}
mysql_close($con);
header('Location:index.php');
?>
```

Comment: have you ever heard of $_SESSION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a cookie called e.g. `$_COOKIE['status_message']` with 60 second timeout.

```
set_cookie('status_message','This is our message',(time()+60));
```

Then when the page is refreshed, check to see if the cookie has any data;

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['status_message'])){
    echo $_COOKIE['status_message'];
    set_cookie('status_message','',(time()-3600));
}
```

This will echo out any populated message and destroy the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Put your $mesag in query string like this

```
header("Location:index.php?msg=$mesag");
```

then use $_GET['msg'] on index.php and get value there and display it.